# View files set for deletion during the next system restart

Tags: windows, ntfs

#### Note:

- **NTFS** - version 3.1 - used [fsutil](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/fsutil.mspx) to obtain information
- Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]

### Question:

- Method (or tool) to obtain, a **list of files** set for **deletion during the next system restart?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a free MS/Sysinternals program called [pendmoves](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897556.aspx) that can show you the list of files waiting to be deleted/moved on reboot.

You can also look at the following registry key for a list of pending operations:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations
```

The API operation that does this is called MoveFileEx() with the MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT option.

More information in [this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/202071).

FYI, to manually add a working entry to this area of the registry you can do the following:

> 1. Start REGEDT32 (W2K) or REGEDIT (WXP) and navigate to:
>      HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session
>      Manager
> 2. W2K: Edit, Add Value..., Data Type: REG_MULTI_SZ, Value Name:
>      PendingFileRenameOperations, OK
>
> WXP: Edit, New, Multi-String Value,
>   [enter] PendingFileRenameOperations
>
> 3. In the Data area, enter "\??\" + filename to be deleted. LFNs may be
>      entered without being embedded in
>      quotes. To delete "C:\Long Directory
>      Name\Long File Name.exe", enter the
>      following data:
>
> \??\C:\Long Directory Name\Long File
>   Name.exe
>
> Then press OK.
>
> 4. The "destination file name" is a null (zero) string. It is entered as
>      follows:
>
> W2K: Edit, Binary, select Data Format:
>   Hex, click at the end of the hex
>   string, enter 0000 (four zeros), OK.
>
> WXP: Right-click the value, choose
>   "Modify Binary Data", click at the end
>   of the hex string, enter 0000 (four
>   zeros), OK.
>
> 5. Close REGEDT32/REGEDIT and reboot to delete the file.

From [this thread.](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-1715654.php)

Of course using [movefile](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897556.aspx) is easier than doing all that.